java.util.ConcurrentModificationException for removing without loops
I am using a MutableMap collection with set as value where I need to add new objects and delete some old ones quite often. I don't use loops but for some reason I still get an java.util.ConcurrentModificationException. Please help, what is my main mistake?
Collection:
val userIdToSessionDataMap: MutableMap<String, MutableSet<UserSessionData>> = mutableMapOf()

Method for removing objects:
private fun removeSessionForUser(userId: String, jti: String) {
    val found = userIdToSessionDataMap[userId]
    found?.removeIf { it.jti == jti }
}

exception:
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.remove(LinkedHashMap.java:769)
    at java.base/java.util.Collection.removeIf(Collection.java:577)
    at com.life.application.service.BroadcastServiceImpl.removeSessionForUser(BroadcastService.kt:57)

Call of removeSessionForUser method:
fun registerSession(userId: String, jti: String): SseEmitter {
    val sseEmitter = SseEmitter(timeout)
    sseEmitter.onTimeout { removeSessionForUser(userId, jti) }
    sseEmitter.onError { removeSessionForUser(userId, jti) }

    val sessionData = UserSessionData(jti, sseEmitter)
    val found = userIdToSessionDataMap[userId]
    if (found != null) {
        found.add(sessionData)
    } else {
        userIdToSessionDataMap[userId] = mutableSetOf(sessionData)
    }
    return sseEmitter
}


Please also show us how removeDataForUser is called, especially if it is called multiple times or from a coroutine.

I added method that calls removeDataForUser and performs adding to userIdToSessionDataMap

@NeverSleeps You posted call to method removeSessionForUser, not removeDataForUser. Did you rename the method or is it a mistake?

sorry, it was just renaming. Now you can see actual version

I think you just want your methods to be atomic. Have you considered using synchronized blocks? Or synchronization with coroutines like mutex or single thread dispatcher?

A ConcurrentModificationException occurs when you try to access a collection (in this case a Set) while it is being modified. This can easily happen because you pass removeSessionForUser as a callback to onTimeout and onError. You have no control over when or how (like, from a separate thread) they are called, therefore it is not surprising that you run into a ConcurrentModificationException.
userIdToSessionDataMap (or at least its values) is a shared mutable state. That always needs additional attention. There are basically two ways to handle it:

Synchronize the access to your collection
Make the collection immutable

They both have their pros and cons, but in your specific case (with server sent events) I would strongly prefer option 2. Option 1 may look easier because you would just need to use a different set implementation when you create a new MutableSet:
userIdToSessionDataMap[userId] = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet<UserSessionData>()
    .apply { add(sessionData) }

But this is not the Kotlin way. That means it will only work when you compile your Kotlin code for the JVM, you cannot use this in Kotlin Multiplatform. In Kotlin, shared mutable state should usually be synchronized where the access occurs and shouldn't be an integral part of the data structure when that wasn't explicitly designed to work with coroutines. Another option would be to use a regular MutableMap but restrict its access with a Mutex.
But instead of exploring this avenue I would recommend to leave the idea of mutable collections behind entirely and embrace option 2: Refactor your code to only use immutable data structures. The general idea is to never modify a collection, instead you create a copy of the collection that already includes the changes you want to make. That way the ConcurrentModificationException is impossible by design.
I would also suggest a flat data structure to make everything easier. If you make userId part of UserSessionData you can use a simple list instead of userIdToSessionDataMap:
var allSessionData: List<UserSessionData> = emptyList()

Instead of userIdToSessionDataMap[userId] you would now use allSessionData.filter { it.userId == userId }.
With this simplified, immutable data structure you can add new data can like this:
val sessionData = UserSessionData(userId, jti, sseEmitter)
allSessionData += sessionData

And this is how data is removed:
allSessionData = allSessionData.filterNot {
    it.userId == userId && it.jti == jti
}

These operations are not atomic. If they were to run in parallel you would not face a ConcurrentModificationException though, instead one modification would overwrite the previous modification.
If you have multiple threads involved you can prevent this problem by either encapsulating allSessionData in a class and only allow the modifications to be done with a Mutex, or you could simply wrap the list in a MutableStateFlow. Your code would then look something like this:
val allSessionData: MutableStateFlow<List<UserSessionData>> = MutableStateFlow(emptyList())

// get all sessions for a given userId
val userSessions = allSessionData.value.filter { it.userId == userId }

// remove all sessions for a given userId and jti
allSessionData.update {
    it.filterNot {
        it.userId == userId && it.jti == jti
    }
}

// add new sessionData
allSessionData.update {
    it + sessionData
}

This update is guaranteed to be atomic. It will wait for already running updates to finish. You can always access the value property to get the current state of the list, but this list will always be immutable and will never change. Instead, changes will result in a new list that can be retrieved by the value property. If you need to react to changes of the list you can even observe that with allSessionData.collect.
Flows are a powerful tool in Kotlin with a lot of features, read more about them here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html

That's a great answer, but all I can say, is that I tried atleast

I do not think that part allSessionData = allSessionData.filterNot {     it.userId == userId && it.jti == jti } will work fine, because of the need to make this block synchronized. And without synchronized there will be a chance that different threads will change this value and lose each other's updates when assigning a new list

Read on, what follows next explains how to solve this.

If you look at your code properly, you are trying to read and write to a MutableMap at the same time. You are using remove (WRITE) and find (READ) functions in the following code leading to modifications concurrently, i.e. at the same time, which is not allowed by a data structure like MutableMap
found?.remove(found.find { it.jti == jti })

You can use either an Iterator object available in the JVM Collections interface or if you want a more Kotlin way of doing things, you can use removeIf method like so
found.entries.removeIf{ it.jti == jti }

There are few other options as well, like using Mark and Remove, which can be found here

Although you should definetly prefer removeIf, the read operation is done here before the write operation and shouldn't interfer. Also, the operations are on the Set, not on the Map. The map is never touched. The code from the question runs fine as it is. The problem is most likely located somewhere else, probably where (and how) removeDataForUser is called. Without knowing more about that the question isn't accurately answerable.

I tried to use found.entries.removeIf{ it.jti == jti }, but it did not help me :(

I have solved my problem so yet:
Collection
val userIdToSessionDataMap = ConcurrentHashMap<String, ConcurrentHashMap<String, UserSessionData>>()

Method for adding objects:
private fun addSession(userId: String, jti: String, sseEmitter: SseEmitter) {
    val sessionDataMap = userIdToSessionDataMap.computeIfAbsent(userId) { ConcurrentHashMap<String, UserSessionData>() }
    sessionDataMap[jti] = UserSessionData(sseEmitter)
}

Method for removing objects:
private fun removeSession(userId: String, jti: String) {
    userIdToSessionDataMap[userId]
        ?.let { sessions -> sessions.remove(jti) != null }
}

Of course, I don't think this is a perfect solution, so if someone sees a problem with this, I'd be glad if they wrote about it.
